# Cant place a div with width=100% next to a div with width=200px?

Tags: html, version-control

I have a Problem with two divs. The first one (DetailWrapper) should be on the left side with a width=100%. But next th this div there should be the second div (RightLinkBar) with a width=200px.

How can i get the two divs next to each other? at the Moment the RightLinkBar div is below the first one.

The Content of the div with the 100% width will be filled dynamically so i dont know how much content it will have. Because of the Background Color it should always have the whole place except the 200px which should be saved for the second div...

the HTML:

```
    <div class="MainWrapper">

     <div class="HeaderWrapper">
     <!--BEGIN Header Bar   -->
     <div class="HeaderBar">
        HeaderLine
     </div>
     <!--End Header Bar   -->
     </div>

     <div class="DetailWrapper">
      <!--BEGIN Detail Bar   -->
     <div class="DetailSection">
        DetailSection
         <div class="HeaderLeft">
            HeaderLeft<br />Overflow so it can have every Size<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test
        </div>
        <div class="NaviGraph">
           NaviGraph<br />and<br />much<br />more<br />stuff<br />so<br />that<br />it<br />needs<br />some<br />space<br />whatever<br />
        </div>
        <div class="Detail">
           Detail <br />one <br />with <br />any <br />height
        </div>
        <div class="Detail">
           Detail <br />two <br />with <br />any <br />height<br />see?<br />its<br />bigger<br />than<br />one
        </div>
        <div class="Detail">
           Detail <br />three <br />with <br />any <br />height<br />see?<br />between 2 and one
        </div>
     </div>
     <!--END Detail Bar   -->
     <!--BEGIN Right Link Bar   -->
     <div class="RightLinkBar">
        RightLinkBar
        <div class="LinkItem">
            Search Div
        </div>
        <div class="LinkItem">
            Link Div One
        </div>
        <div class="LinkItem">
            Link Div Two
        </div>
     </div>
     <!--END Right Link Bar   -->
     </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.MainWrapper 
{
background-color: #FFFFFF; 
border: 1px solid #000000; 
height: 1200px; 
width: 1000px; 
background-color: Gray; 
top: 100px; 
left: 6%; 
position: absolute;
}
.HeaderWrapper
{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.HeaderBar
{
background-color: #E1E1F0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 50px;
}
.DetailWrapper
{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
.DetailSection
{
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
float: left; 
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.HeaderLeft
{
background-color: #E1E1F0; 
width: 100%; 
overflow: auto;
}
.NaviGraph
{
background-color: #E1E1F0; 
width: 100%; 
height:300px;
}
.Detail
{
background-color: #E1E1F0; 
width: 100%; 
overflow: auto;
}
.RightLinkBar
{
background-color: #FFFFFF; 
width: 200px; 
height: 100%; 
float: right;
}
.LinkItem
{
background-color: #E1E1F0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100px;
}
```

I hope someone can help me out here!

Beste Regards

Khaine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Width:100% is relative to the parent element, so there is no 200px left for the other div. You could for example use width:80% for the left div and width:20% for the right div.

```
.DetailWrapper
{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width:80%;
}
.RightLinkBar
{
background-color: #FFFFFF; 
width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply :) but that didnt help me in this case since the right dive has to have the 200px static.

Comment: @Khaine how come you accepted an answer that doesn't fix your problem?

Comment: You're welcome ;) It might be better to go for two static divs if you need the right one to be 200px. Maybe make the left one 760px, the 960px layout is used very often, for example on StackOverflow.

Comment: when i have a width of 1000px of my main wrapper i forgot that the 20% are always my 200px which i Need. So the first answer of mine wasnt right and the answer of plvdmeer fixed my Problem. Sorry for that!